# Android date picker calculation , before and after a specific date

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, datepicker

I have an application which use the current date and a date that is chose by user using date picker as follow:

- If the date that the user chose is more than the current date +280 day,
  some code will be executed.
- If the date that the user chose is less than the current date , some 
  code will be executed.

I used this code to do so ..

```
    Calendar start2 = Calendar.getInstance();

       int birthYear = birthDayDatePicker.getYear();
            int birthMonth = birthDayDatePicker.getMonth();
            int birthDay = birthDayDatePicker.getDayOfMonth();

            start2.set(birthYear, birthMonth, birthDay);

           Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
           cal2.setTime(birthDate);
           cal2.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,daysToAdd);
 birthDayChosenCalender.set(birthYear,birthMonth,birthDay);
         MaxBirthDayCalender.set(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay);

          long diff = birthDayChosenCalender.getTimeInMillis() - MaxBirthDayCalender.getTimeInMillis(); //result in millis
          long daysBetween = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
          System.out.println("Days between ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"+daysBetween);

          if(MaxBirthDayCalender.before(birthDayChosenCalender) && daysBetween <= 280){

do sth }
```

Is there any other clean way to do that ! because this way is not working well !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other clean way to do it is to use the Joda Time library.

Other than that, everything can be done using millis and a single calendar instance:

```
Calendar pickedDate = new GregorianCalendar(
        picker.getYear(), 
        picker.getMonth(), 
        picker.getDayOfMonth());
long pickedTime = pickedDate.getTimeInMillis();
long now = new Date().getTime();

if (pickedTime - now <= (280 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) { // 280 days in milliseconds
  // ...
}
```

Should cover the requirement:

> I have an application which use the current date and a date that is chose by user using date picker as follow:
>
> - If the date that the user chose is more than the current date +280 day, some code will be executed.
> - If the date that the user chose is less than the current date , some code will be executed.

Comment: PickedDate has the date from the date picker and now is the current date ?? and this if do what ? can u please explain ?